# Python Get System Environment Variable Linux

Tags: python, python-2.7, environment-variables

I've exposed one system environment variable say `KEY1` with value `VALUE1` in `/etc/profile` (I know, I know, it's probably bad)

Now in my shell if I do

```
$ echo $KEY1
VALUE1
```

But when I do

```
$ python -c "import os; print os.environ.get('KEY1')"
None
$
```

Why might this be the case?

Comment: Instead of keeping it in /etc/profile you can create a bash shell and pass the KEY1 as arguments to python script.

Comment: Multiple different types of apps are using it so can't pass argument to python script.

Answer (score 1):

You might not have exported the variable. You can think of export as a way of making a shell variable public and not private to the shell. Take a look at the [export man page](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/exporth.html).

```
➜  ~ K=1    
➜  ~ echo $K 
1
➜  ~ python -c "import os; print os.environ.get('K')"   
None
➜  ~ export K=1
➜  ~ python -c "import os; print os.environ.get('K')"
1
```

Comment: I've added the variable in the `/etc/profile`. Which is global store for environment variables. I don't have to export it again.

Comment: Even if you stick it in ``/etc/profile``, you still need to have that ``export`` statement. If you don't, it isn't available to sub processes from the shell in which it was set. So have you used ``export`` when you set it?