# How to get linux system variable in python

Tags: python, linux, system-variable

I add a variable called `env` to `/etc/profile`, but I didn't `export` it, now I want to get the value of `env` in `python`, but I get nothing, my code is as below:

```
>>> import os
>>> env = os.environ.get('env')
>>> print env
None
```

Comment: Please don't post code in picture, add it to the post instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Get System Environment Variable Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44919298/python-get-system-environment-variable-linux)

Comment: just try os.environ  to get a list of environmental variables and check if `env` exist

Comment: Did the changes apply to you console session? Check with `env` on the console!

Answer (score 0):

thanks for everybody, i've solved this problem, the reason is that I didn't use the upper case of 'env', although I wrote lowercase in the profile file, I must get it in capitals.

```
# my code like this:
import os
environ = os.environ  
env = environ.get('ENV')
# profile like this:
env=production
```